# Active Record Limiting All Queries to a Date Range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to be able to limit all queries on a controller to say `y > Date > x`. I tried to use a before_filter but couldn't find a good solution. One possible solution would be to go to each query and add an additional `where` filter, but I feel like there's a better way to do it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### default_scope

If you want all requests to a model to have the same constraints, try [`default_scope`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods/default_scope)

```
# models/activity.rb
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { where("date between ? and ?", 5.days.ago, Date.current) }
end
```

So if you call:

```
Activity.all
```

You will only get back activities in the date range specified by the default_scope.

#### scopes

If you instead want to be able to specify a date range for different queries, you could create a scope that you would have to explicitly call:

```
# models/activity.rb
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :between_dates, ->(begin_date,end_date) {
    where("date between ? and ?", begin_date, end_date)
  }
end
```

Which you would call in your controller like:

```
Activity.between_dates(5.days.ago, Date.current)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Any idea how I can pass parameters into this from the view?

Comment: as in you want to be able to supply a custom date range for specific requests? do you also want a default date range on all queries where you dont explicitly specify a range?

Comment: Yup. Just being able to pass in a custom date will be more important actually.

Answer (score 0):

jstim's answer is likely the right one for your problem and the limiting should be done in the MODEL and not the controller.  MODELs work with data and Controllers handle the interaction between models, views and requests.

Also see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

If however it MUST be done in the controller then simply apply the filter to your instance variables.  e.g. @post.default_scope { where("date between ? and ?", 5.days.ago, Date.current) }